# MongoDB replication with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, database-replication

I configured Spring with MongoDB on my local machine, without replication, and everything works fine.
I also have a replica set that works fine.

Now I tried to add the replica set, but the reads/writes still go to my local machine!

This is my configuration, host1-3 are virtual machines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

<mongo:repositories base-package="my.repositories" />

<mongo:mongo replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="my_db" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Anyone has ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Edit:
Ok so I found the problem, just needed to add mongo-ref to the factory. So the correct configuration is:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="my_db" mongo-ref="mongo" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem, just needed to add mongo-ref to the factory. So the correct configuration is:

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017">
<mongo:db-factory dbname="my_db" mongo-ref="mongo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Writes will always go to the primary. Reads go to the primary by default unless you change the  [Read Preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) in your use of the [Java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-replica-set-semantics/).

Comment: I know, but the primary isn't my local machine, it's host1 (VM).
The problem is that both reads and writes go to the local host instead of the VM (which is what I tried to configure spring to do).